# Why does this authentication HTTP request to Firebase fail (return error 400)

Tags: angular, firebase, httprequest

I made sure that the API was correct:
'''
[https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=[API_KEY]](https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=%5BAPI_KEY%5D)
''' [source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-create-email-password)

Any my API_Key was also correct:
[image]

The request (called and subscribed to in a component):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

interface AuthResponseData {
  idToken:string;
  email:string;
  refreshToken:string;
  expiresIn:string;
  localId:string;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {


  signUp(){
    return this.http.post<AuthResponseData>('https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=[AIzaSyC4JiHH6Cp1eeudn5Yu5lSkB-_gDfNudeo]',
    {
      email: "email@gmail.com",
      password: "passwordx",
      returnSecureToken: true
    })
  }

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
}
```

But I keep having a 400 error:

s:23

> POST
> [https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=[AIzaSyC4JiHH6Cp1eeudn5Yu5lSkB-_gDfNudeo]](https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=%5BAIzaSyC4JiHH6Cp1eeudn5Yu5lSkB-_gDfNudeo%5D)
> 400 scheduleTask @ zone.js:2710 scheduleTask @ zone.js:396
> onScheduleTask

Answer (score 0):

Removing the brackets around my API_Key solved the problem.